# How to remove the "quotation marks" inside a string in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string similar to this "A["B"]C" I need this string to look like `"A[B]C"`. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at string functions?  Have you tried using `replace()` ?

Comment: Yes! I looked further and I was using it in the wrong way! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use re.sub for this.

```
import re

string = "[6->['A', 'B']; 7->['ABC']]"
string = re.sub("'","",string)
```

That will remove all ' characters from the string.

To get rid of " as well:

```
string = re.sub("['\"]","",string)
```

Comment: Why re.sub when you could just use str.replace?

Comment: Both work fine. str.replace is likely more fitting, though. I just though of re.sub first and it worked.